# In a Chrome extension, why does a closed tab still exist when the callback passed to chrome.tabs.remove() is called?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I pass a callback to `chrome.tabs.remove()`, I'd expect the callback to be called once the tab has been removed from the UI *and* and the current Chrome state.  In other words, if I run the following code in the background page of an extension that has the `tabs` permission, I'd expect it to generate an error, since trying to get a tab that doesn't exist sets `runtime.lastError`:

```
var tabs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "chrome://newtab" }, tab => tabs.push(tab));
}

setTimeout(() => {
    var {id} = tabs[1];
    chrome.tabs.remove(id, () => chrome.tabs.get(id, 
        tab => console.log(id, tab)));
}, 2000);
```

But that's not what happens.  Three new blank tabs are opened and two seconds later the second one is closed, but the tab that was closed is still returned when calling `chrome.tabs.get()` in the callback that was passed to `chrome.tabs.remove()`.  You'll see the full details of the removed tab logged to the console in the callback.

This seems like a bug in Chrome.  What possible use could there be for a callback in `chrome.tabs.remove()` to be called *before* the tab is removed?  Do I actually have to add an event listener for `chrome.tabs.onRemoved` before trying to remove a tab, just so I can be reliably notified when a tab is fully removed?

Comment: This is how it was implemented [10 years ago](https://codereview.chromium.org/88053) and I see no  good reason for it to work like that. Most probably it was easier to implement or maybe it was a mistake. Consider reporting on https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [wOxxOm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539170/in-a-chrome-extension-why-does-a-closed-tab-still-exist-when-the-callback-passe#comment105249191_59539170) above, this does seem like a bug or lazy implementation in Chrome, and the only workaround I can see is to add an event listener for `onRemoved`.

I ended up adding an event handler when my extension's popup window opened, but if you only wanted to be notified when your extension closes a tab, you could use something like this to get called back after the tab has been fully removed:

```
function closeTab(tabID, callback)
{
    function handleTabRemoved(tabID, removeInfo)
    {
        chrome.tabs.onRemoved.removeListener(handleTabRemoved);
        callback(tabID, removeInfo);
    }

    chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(handleTabRemoved);
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabID);
}

closeTab(123, tabID => console.log(`Closed ${tabID}`);
```

(There's a potential edge case this doesn't handle where the user is closing a tab at exactly the same moment your extension is, but that's probably not worth worrying about.)